# Problems with symfony tests after minor version upgrade

Tags: php, symfony

I have a simple web application originally built in Symfony 4.2, now trying to update it to Symfony 4.4. I updated the composer.json and removed the composer.lock and symfony.lock files and the vendor directory.

Everything seemed fine, except for my tests.

I got the warning.

> 1x: The "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\AbstractController::get()" method is considered final. It may change without further notice as of its next major version. You should not extend it from "App\Controller\ResourceController".

This seemed to be because my routes.yaml was

```
main:
  path: /{path}
  defaults:
    path: ''
  requirements:
    path: '.+'
  methods: [HEAD, GET]
  controller: App\Controller\ResourceController::get
```

So I switched it to

```
main:
  path: /{path}
  defaults:
    path: ''
  requirements:
    path: '.+'
  methods: HEAD|GET
  controller: App\Controller\ResourceController::getResource
```

and altered the function name in ResourceController.

If I run `php ./bin/console server:start` I can use the application.

But my tests all report

```
5) App\Tests\Model\RDFSourceTest::testGetRDFSourceJSON
InvalidArgumentException: The controller for URI "/nobel_914.ttl" is not callable. Method "get" on class "App\Controller\ResourceController" should be public and non-abstract.

/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Controller/ControllerResolver.php:88
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:129
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/HttpKernel.php:68
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Kernel.php:201
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/http-kernel/Client.php:65
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/framework-bundle/Client.php:131
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/vendor/symfony/browser-kit/Client.php:404
/sw/var/www/trellis-ldp/static-ldp/test/Model/RDFSourceTest.php:77
```

So it seems like it is not picking up the change in the `routes.yaml` but I have tried to `composer clear-cache` and `composer dump-autoload`. I'm out of ideas?

Comment: Did you declare this `ResourceController` of yours as a public service?

Comment: Why are you using `ResourceController` ? Do you want to render a template directly or something like that?

Comment: Hi @emix, yes the controller is an extension of the AbstractController class.

Comment: Hi @qdequippe, the code is a read only linked data platform implementation. So it reads files off disk and provides access to them compliant with the W3 spec. So it provides binary files in whatever format they should be in and RDF in whatever serialization you request ( via the Accept header) - https://www.w3.org/TR/ldp/

Comment: What's the problem with the given error message? If you change the link between the route and the controller action in your YAML file, have you also changed the name of the action method?

Comment: Hi @Nico Haase, yes I have. If I run the internal symfony (PHP) server it works fine. It's only the phpunit tests that have this problem.